# How to get option value from a selectbox in php using mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have created this function for a selectbox which is added through jquery dynamic table.
the issue is that i get only the first value in all the rows.
Please tell me how to correct this error

```
<?php
function ShowCategory(){

$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "erp";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
    $sql = "select * from category";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $category = "<option>Select</option>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        //$id = $row['category_id'];
        $cat = $row['category_name'];
        //$category .= '<option value=\'$cat\'>' . $row['category_name'] . '</option>';
        $category .= "<option value=".$cat.">".$cat."</option>";
        //echo $category;
    }

   return $category;
//  print_r($category);
}
//echo ShowCategory();
?>

And the function for adding dynamic rows in jquery is

<script>

var rowcount=1;
function addRow()
{
    alert('hello');
    var option = "<?php echo ShowCategory();?>";

    var category='<td><select class="select chosen-select sel_category" style="width:150px;" name="category[]'+rowcount+'" onchange="getcatid(this);" id="cat_name">'+option+'</select></td>';
    var subcat='<td><select class="form-control select sel_subcat" style="width:150px;" name="sub_category[]'+rowcount+'" id="sub_cat_name " onchange="getsubcatid(this);"></select></td>';
    var product="<td><select class='sel_model form-control select' style='width:150px;' id='product_name'  name='product_name[]"+rowcount+"' ></select></td>";
    var quantity="<td><input type='text' class='txt_quantity form-control' name='quantity[]"+rowcount+"' onchange='total_calculate(this)'/></td>";
    var price="<td><input type='text' class='txt_price form-control' name='price_to_distributor[]"+rowcount+"' onchange='total_calculate(this)'></td>";
    var vat="<td><select class='sel_vat form-control' name='tax_id[]"+rowcount+"' onchange='total_calculate(this)'><option value='2'>2</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='12.5'>12.5</option></select></td>";
    var status="<td><select class='sel_status form-control' name='status[]"+rowcount+"'><option value='0'>De-Activated</option><option value='1')>Activated</option></select></td>";
    var total="<td><input type='text' class='txt_total form-control' name='total[]"+rowcount+"' readonly/></td>";
    var del="<td><img width='16' height='16' src='images/remove.png' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='delRow(this)'/></td>";

    var row="<tr>"+category+subcat+product+quantity+price+vat+status+total+del+"</tr>";
    $("table#tbl_product tbody").append(row);
    selectpicker();
    rowcount++;
};
```

the function returns the category but after selecting it through the row i am able to select only the first category and corresponding subcategory and product
in all the other rows

Thanks

Comment: you need to specify `<select name='something'></select>`

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.yourwebskills.com/mysqldropdown.php the example makes use of mysql_ functions which are deprecated so you should not use them.

Answer (score 1):

***PHP***

```
 $select = $_POST['select'];
```

Put this inside the `<form>`

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i got your point , but i am unable to figure out how to use that in my php function ShowCategory()? And select box is in js function

Comment: what wil be in seeLocation.php?

Comment: its the action file action='anypage.php'

Comment: we can send value of option selected to this page ... am i correct?

Comment: do you want an easier way to send the value without JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: Yes Please . Can you help me like that